# Does Hinduism allow siblings to have their marriages at the same time?

Tags: marriage, tradition, customs

Let us consider the following scenario:

X, Y are children to same parents and are going to marry a, b respectively.  Are there any rules in Hinduism that does not allow X and Y to have their marriage at the same time?

If there are no such rules, are there any examples in Hindu scriptures where siblings got marry individually at the same time?

Note that *Y may be the brother or sister for X and X can be of any gender*.

Comment: IMHO The best example I can give you is of the four sons of Dasaratha Maharaja marrying the four daughters of Janaka Maharaja(s).

Answer (score 5):

If they are brothers then the rule is that the younger must not marry before the elder. Regarding marrying at the same time, nothing is mentioned anywhere AFAIK.

This is mentioned in all the Smritis. Here I'm using the Parashara Smriti (PS) as my reference.

> An elder brother remaining unmarried while a younger marries, and that
>   same younger brother himself who marries before his elder brother, and
>   the woman who becomes the wife of such a younger brother, together
>   with the person who gives away the bride, and the priest who
>   officiates at the marriage, — all these are doomed to hell.
>
> A double Krichchhra is the penance ordained for the said elder
>   brother, a single Krichchhra for the bride herself. He who gave away
>   the bride must perform a Krichchhra and an Atikrichchhra ; while the
>   priest must observe the Chandrayana rite.
>
> **PS 4- 25,26**

However, in certain scenarios, a younger brother marrying before his elder brother is also allowed.

> If the elder brother be a hunchback, a dwarf, a eunuch, an idiot, or
>   hoarse of voice, (probably the word
>   * gadgada ' here means ' a person of an indistinct utterance,' like the dumb), or blind from birth, or deaf, or dumb, there is no sin in
>   the younger's marrying first. 
>   **27**

I don't know the answers for any of the other possibilities.

Comment: You have the example of Rama and his brothers' marriages.

Comment: I was talking about the Smritis talking about or approving the act.. In Itihasas the characters are shown doing a variety of acts.. does not mean that all those acts are approved all the time.. @Surya

Comment: Well reasoned but I guess since Rama is Vigrahavan Dharmah I think it would be approved..

Comment: Well u can say so but people still ask Qs like "Was it ok for Krishna to drink alcohol?" "Was it ok that Rama ate meat?" and all sorts of similar Qs.. So i guess people need to convince themselves with what the law books say on the issues... @Surya

Comment: @Surya They were not born in the same womb..